# Choosing image size based on the size in cm

Tags: resolution, pixel, size

I need to search images which are suitable to be printed on a photographic paper whose size are 220 cm x 53 cm (length x height).

How can I choose the image size?

If I use for example the Google's tool Advanced Image Search, the option I can choose are the ones in the following picture; it seems that the image size is a sort of resolution here:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer, get the biggest ones you can get.

Let's do some math.

220cm to inches are 86.61 on the long side. 20.86 on the short side.

A good resolution for a big print is **100PPI**.

So you need images of around **8600px** on the long side. A more realistic resolution is **6000px** on the long side. Those will be fine.

**6000px over 86.6 inches are 70PPI, it is still a decent resolution.**

---

You can use a resampler to reduce the pixel size. Use https://www.upscayl.org/ and configure it so you have 2x the size. A 6000px file will be at 12000 which is a great resolution.

[image]

---

If you need free photos, do not use the Google search engine as your source, go directly to image banks. Free are pixabay.com and pexels.com. You can find photos at a good resolution there.
There are some other image banks. Search for the websites, not for the images.

---

Complementing:

I wrote in the comment **the resolution on a big print is a range, not a specific value.**

Imagine you like a photo you found on a decent website. Here is a screen capture of Pixabay:

[image]

It has the 6000px on the base as I commented.

But if it only had let's say 4000px and works fine with a resampling of 2X it is fine. This photo only has 4000px on the base, as you are looking for horizontal orientation.

[image]

Even if the photo does not have many details, like an abstract image, some resampling algorithms do a good job. And you could work with even smaller images. But depends on the content of the image.

[image]

Comment: according to https://www.unitconverters.net/ the size should be 8314.9606299 x 2003.1496063 right?

Comment: It is a range, not a specific value. Again, a good number to start looking at and not limiting your options is about 6000px on the long side. If the image is awesome it could be less.